# Linq in C# Query needed - One to many table relationship, one to many records needed

Tags: c#, linq

need help to accomplish this in linq.

I have 3 tables.

1. Customers
2. CustumerOrder
3. OrderDetails

I need to list in one query all customers ( only if they have placed atleast one order) with all the orders for each customer only if order value is greated than 100.

Regards,

Harsh

Comment: Please add more details than just the table names.  For example, columns.  Even better, since this is LinqToSql, provide your class/property names instead.

Comment: Hi Kirk, Lets say there are below columns - 1. Customers - CustomerId, CustomerName 2. CustomerOrder - OrderId, CutomerId, OrderAmount 3. OrderDetails - OrderId, OrderDate......   Now please let me know how can I get the collection like Dictionary<Customer, List<CustomerOrder>> using Linq query....... Hope this is much explanatory. This is just common customer, order scenario, you can assume the other details as per the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you want something like this:

```
from c in Customers
where c.CustomerOrders.Any()
select new
{
  customer,
  Orders = 
    from co in c.CustomerOrders
    where co.TotalPrice > 100
    select co.OrderDetails
}
```

Or, if you don't have an "TotalPrice" column in the CustomerOrder table, replace the inner query with this:

```
Orders =
  from cp in c.CustomerOrders
  where co.OrderDetails.Sum (od => od.Price) > 100
  select co.OrderDetails
```

Edit: if you want to include customers only with at least one order with OrderTotalPrice more than 100, use a **let** statement:

```
from c in Customers
let highValueOrders = 
    from co in c.CustomerOrders
    where co.TotalPrice > 100
    select co.OrderDetails
where highValueOrders.Any()
select new
{
  customer,
  highValueOrders
}
```

You can add more conditions in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I really appreciate that quick response.

But this query does not take into consideration the part that - 

Customer would be in the final list only if he has atleast one order with OrderTotalPrice more than 100.

+ 

Actually I had few more conditions here for inclusion of Customer in final selection like - 
Select Customer only if it has atleast one order with Age > 30 if Customer is of type "Regular" customer or Age > 35 if Customer is of type "Rare".
CustomerType is stored in CustomerDetails table.



Please help me with this..

Regards,
Harshal

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe.. Few Questions -  1. Can we call C# functions inside the LINQ query or Lambda Expression? I need this to calculate Age, in my database there is a Birthday field and i would need a Age to be calculated from this field                                                               2. How can i get the list from above LINQ query, Now i need only Customers from the above Query having more number of rows woth Customer details. I am really confused here. Dont know how can i pass this to UI. Can I get something like Dictionary<Customer, List<CustomerDetails>>?

Comment: YOu can't call your own functions inside lambda expressions that go through a L2S or EF pipeline. For a workaround, check out this: http://mathgeekcoder.blogspot.com/2008/07/advanced-domain-model-queries-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess based off some assumptions:

```
var result = 
    from customer in Customers.Where(a => a.CustomerOrder.Count > 0)
    from order in CustomerOrder.Where(a => a.OrderDetails.Sum(b => b.Price) > 100)
    select new
    {
        customer, 
        order.OrderDetails
    }
```